# Laravel - query, making a search

Tags: php, laravel, search, eloquent, where-clause

Okay I'm making a search in my Laravel project and I'm using `whereBetween` clause, but it's not working properly. Let me show the code than I'll explain.

So this is my `SearchController` function for search:

```
/**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     */
    public function automobilipretraga(Request $request)
    {
        $autoQuery = DB::table('automobils');

      
        if (
            $from = $request->input('from')
            && $to = $request->input('to')
        ) {
            $autoQuery->whereBetween('price', [$from, $to]);
        }

        //vracanje rezultata
        $automobili = $autoQuery->get();

        return view('site.automobili.pretraga')->with('automobili', $automobili);
    }
```

And in my `search.blade.php`:

```
<div id="collapsecijena" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="cijena">
   <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="cs-model-year">
         <div class="cs-select-filed">
            <input type="text" name="from">
         </div>
         <span style="color:black;">TO</span>
         <div class="cs-select-filed">
            <input type="text" name="to">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So I have these two inputs named `from` and `to`.

For example, I have three cars posts and first have a `price of 15`, second one have a `price of 45` and a third one have a `price of 80`. When I search price between `20 and 50` it doesn't work, it shows me car post with `price of 15`, but when I change my search to between `10 and 30` it works.
It's like it only counts `$to` variable and not `from`.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This will work? `$autoQuery->whereBetween('price', [$request->from, $request->to]);`

Comment: Thank you so much, I think it works perfect now! Let me just quick check it. Why is this working, can you explain me please ?

Comment: Problem here `if (
            $from = $request->input('from')
            && $to = $request->input('to')
        )`

Comment: What should I do with that line of code ? Just delete it and leave it like ```if { $autoQuery->whereBetween('price', [$request->from, $request->to]); }``` ?

Comment: I answered your question, I learned something special from this, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is on the **if else statement**
You can define a variable as `integer` on if  statement :

```
if($x = 33 && $y = 44){
  echo $x; // output 33
}
```

But you can't define a variable as **string** under if statement, it gives you the **boolean** result, as like :

```
if($x = "33" && $y = "44"){
  echo $x; // output 1
}
```

Here when you passed a variable by **Request**, it gives you an `string`, not `integer`.

Your code will be like this :

```
public function automobilipretraga(Request $request)
{
    $autoQuery = DB::table('automobils');

    if (
       $from = $request->input('from')
       && $to = $request->input('to')
       ) {
           $autoQuery->whereBetween('price', [(float)$from = $request->input('from'), (float)$to = $request->input('to')]); // float will convert this string as float value like 10.00 
         }

     //vracanje rezultata
     $automobili = $autoQuery->get();

    return view('site.automobili.pretraga')->with('automobili', $automobili);
}
```

Comment: I use `(float)` because its better to convert a `string` to a `number` value, you can use `(int)` too. `(float)` gives you a decimal value, where `(int)` give you a number without decimal. You can ignore `(float)` too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting input to an integer

```
$from = (int)$from
$to = (int)$to
```

Comment: I just did like this ```$cijenaod = (int)$request->input('cijenaod') && $cijenado = (int)$request->input('cijenado')``` but it stay the same issue

Comment: What happens if you replace the $from and $to varaibles with just numbers in your code,
$autoQuery->whereBetween('price', [20, 80]);

Comment: There is a problem with that because than my variables ```$from and $to``` stay empty and than it is returning me every car posts

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your usage of `$request`. You sure there is no double `==` or something like that in the `if` in your actual code?

---

Besides that, I recommend using a more elegant form for your controller method. It also allows using only one input, `from` or `to` (if that's something you want to allow your users to search for):

```php
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 */
public function automobilipretraga(Request $request)
{
    $automobili = DB::table('automobils')
        ->when($request->input('from'), function ($query, $from) {
            $query->where('price', '>=', $from);
        })
        ->when($request->input('to'), function ($query, $to) {
            $query->where('price', '<=', $to);
        })
        ->get();

    return view('site.automobili.pretraga')->with('automobili', $automobili);
}
```

Please note: The `when($condition, $callback)` method passes the result of `$condition` as second argument to the `$callback` function. If you were to enter `0` as value for `$request->input('from')`, `$condition` would evaluate to `false` and the query constraint would not be added. In such case you therefore need to use `$request->input('from') !== null` as `$condition`, which requires you to access `$request->input('from')` explicitely in the callback. Don't forget to add the `use` clause on the callback though:`function ($query, $condition) use ($request) { ... }`